# Entity Component System in Python

Tags: python, entity-component-system

Me and a team of junior developers are making a role playing game.  We would like to make something similar to https://bunk.town/  I have only made a Tetris clone which doesn't require much knowledge about game architecture; however, this game will.  Is an ECS architecture a good fit for this kind of game?  If so how should i go about implementing it in python?

I know that one of the major drawbacks when making an ECS with python is the inability to utilize the cache.  There is the advantage of being able to compose entities easily and archetypes may help iteration speeds.

I'm working with people relatively new to game programming.  They lack experience and im not sure if i should make something like an ecs yet.

I tried putting something together but I'm partly unsatisfied with how it turned out.  Its not finished, but i can loop over a specific group of components in an archetype.  Id appreciate any guidance as Ive struggled with this in the past. Here is the source code.

```
class Component:
    pass


class Archetable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entities = []
        self.type = set()

    def __iter__(self):
        for entity in self.entities:
            yield entity

    def over_components(self, *Components):
        for components in self.entities:
            entity = []
            for component in components:
                if type(component) not in Components:
                    continue
                index = Components.index(type(component))
                entity.insert(index, component)

            yield entity


class Camera(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0


class Controller(Component):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__


arche = Archetable()
arche.entities.append([Controller()])
arche.entities.append([Controller()])
arche.type.add(Controller)
arche.type.add(Camera)

for controller, in arche.over_components(Controller):
    print(controller)
```

Comment: "There is the advantage of being able to compose entities easily" This is, IMHO, a very interesting advantage of using an ECS. "but I'm partly unsatisfied with how it turned out." Why? What kind of improvement are you seeking?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I dont know how to make ids that remain valid after entities are deleted and added.  I could just have references to a list of components instead of an id, but most ecs use ids as a means of retrieving and modifying entities.

Comment: Try editing your question to ask about that specifically.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit soon.